# Visual Studio DataSet Designer doesn't accept working SQL statement with function call and parameter

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, visual-studio, dataset

In an untyped dataset, there are several SQL statements, defined by hand which take one or more parameters defined in this fashion: `WHERE someId = :someId`.

Now I need to call an Oracle function, which takes a to strings as input parameters. First a culture code and second the value which needs to be translated.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT d.DegreeId, Translate(:CultureCode, d.Degree) as Degree
FROM DEGREE d
```

When I try to save this query Visual Studio throws out a warning stating

```
Error in SELECT clause: expression near '('.
Missing FROM clause.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
Unable to parse query text.
```

Executed via SQL Developer against the database directly it returns all results. How can I fix this error?

Some additional information:

- Visual Studio 2013 Prof.
- Odp.Net to connect to database
- Oracle client 11.2.0 installed
- ODT for Visual Studio 2013 ship with the Oracle client 12+. Unfortunatly this client only supports ORacle database versions 10.2 and higher. Since I am working with 9i, this is out of the question.

Comment: Probably because VS expects MSSQL-like query and it uses `@` not `:` as parameter placeholder. You can try to install [ODT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) to solve your problem.

Comment: If I recall correctly, 11.2.0 is the newest I can work with, because 12 doesnt support the database server anymore, because it's too old. ODT 12 does support VS2013, but I can't install those, because I wouldn't be able to connect to the server anymore.
And `:` as a parameter placeholder works just fine. No problem here